# DateRangePicker disable dates interval

Tags: loops, daterangepicker

Table has two records, but only one date range is displayed.
I wrote next code:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($res8)==0){
echo "<script>

$(function() {
      $('input[name=datetimes]').daterangepicker({
        opens: 'left',
        minDate: moment(),
        maxDate: moment().add(1, 'year'),
 'locale': {
        'format': 'DD.MM.YYYY',
        'firstDay': 1
    },
    });
    });
</script>";
} else   while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res8)){
    
$date1 = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($row['date_start']));
$date2 = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($row['date_finish'])+1);
 
    echo "<script>

$(function() {
      $('input[name=datetimes]').daterangepicker({
        opens: 'left',
        minDate: moment(),
        maxDate: moment().add(1, 'year'),
         'locale': {
        'format': 'DD.MM.YYYY',
        'firstDay': 1
    },
            isInvalidDate: function(date) {
                    var dateRanges = [
                            { 'start': moment('".$date1."'), 'end': moment('".$date2."').add(1, 'day') }
                    ];
                    return dateRanges.reduce(function(bool, range) {
                            return bool || (date >= range.start && date <= range.end);
                    }, false);
        }
    });
    });
</script>";
  }
```

Where i have mistake?
The php loop works correctly and displays all dates if the variable is called.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbr9h.png)